# Gfortran : Segmentation fault with long character

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, character, gfortran

A small test program returns a segmentation fault with gfortran (4.4.5) on linux 64bit. The fault is not present with n=2_8**22_8. Gdb indicates the segmentation fault occurs in function mylen during the first iteration of the loop.

```
allocate, stat=           0
size :              8388608
len, switch=false :              8388608
Segmentation fault
```

Thanks

```
function mylen(abc,n, switch) 

implicit none

logical, intent(in) :: switch
integer(kind=8), intent(in) :: n
logical, dimension(1:n), intent(in) :: abc
integer(kind=8) :: mylen
character(len=size(abc,dim=1,kind=8)) :: tmp
integer(kind=8) :: i

mylen=len(tmp,kind=8)
if (switch) then
  do i=1,len(tmp,kind=8)
    tmp(i:i)='a'
  enddo
endif

end function mylen

program test

implicit none

integer(kind=8) :: n
logical, allocatable :: abc(:)
integer(kind=8) :: mylen
integer :: ierr

n=2_8**23_8
allocate(abc(n),stat=ierr)
print *,'allocate, stat=',ierr
print *,'size :', size(abc,dim=1,kind=8)
print *,'len, switch=false :', mylen(abc,n,.false.)
print *,'len, switch=true  :', mylen(abc,n,.true.)

end program test
```

Comment: I find no problem with gfortran version 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 10.04. Can you update gfortran?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :-/

Comment: You may try to install an alternate compiler, without updating the one installed with OS. See here : http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries If you try this, you may have to set some environment variables (LIBRARY_PATH or alike).

Comment: I suspect stack space has overflowed because of dynamic arrays declared in mylen. A workaround would be to declare them as allocatable and allocate them.

Comment: @darthbith: using a gfortran 4.8.2 64bit binary, I have reproduced the segmentation fault. Can you post the output of "ulimit -a"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this, and realized that if the character array is too large, you blow the stack. If you use an allocatable length string and allocate that at the top of "mylen", it goes on the heap and the program works.

Comment: Nice solution. Can you tell me what part of the stack in "ulimit -a" is responsible for the error? Thanks

Comment: @Sean. Damned, you had already found when I wrote my comment :-)

Comment: @user1824346, I'm not sure "ulimit -a" will help you much here: actually, with -a, all limits are to their max, and there is indeed a max stack space, even in that case (probably depends on machine and OS, I think I have seen once 64MB, but you can check with "limits"). You'd better not rely on this, and declare allocatable arrays. It souldn't change anything to program logic, anyway.

Comment: I believe ulimit -s is the overall stack size. But as @arbautjc says, the OS may set a hard limit that you can't exceed.